# How to make it circular on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am unable to make it circular on iphone

```
 CGPoint addLines[] =
{
    CGPointMake(10.0, 90.0),
    CGPointMake(70.0, 60.0),
    CGPointMake(130.0, 120.0),
    CGPointMake(190.0, 150.0),
    CGPointMake(250.0, 60.0),
    CGPointMake(310.0, 90.0),
};
CGContextAddLines(context, addLines, sizeof(addLines)/sizeof(addLines[0]));
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Please dont post circular code, as I want to make irregular circular through lines, and how to make my edges smooth also, instead of sharp

Comment: Since you seem to be trying to draw a circular shape using line segments, make sure that you call CGPathCloseSubpath() at the end to close the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try like This-

```
CGPoint addLines[] = {
    CGPointMake(10.0, 90.0),
    CGPointMake(70.0, 60.0),
    CGPointMake(70.0, 60.0), 
    CGPointMake(130.0, 120.0),
    ...
};

CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, addLines,nooflines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps looking for [CGContextAddArcToPoint()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17002)?